# Efficiently test matrix rows and columns with numpy

Tags: python, performance, numpy, matrix, sparse-matrix

I am trying to remove both the row i and column i when both the row i **and** column i contains all 0s. For example in this case we can see that row 0 is all zeros and column 0 is all zeros and thus row and column 0 is removed. Same with row column pair 2 and 4. Row 1 is all zeros but column 1 is not so neither are removed.

```
[0,0,0,0,0]
[0,1,0,1,0]
[0,0,0,0,0]
[0,0,0,0,0]
[0,0,0,0,0]
```

would become

```
[1,1]
[0,0]
```

Another example:

```
[0,0,1,0,0,1]
[0,0,0,0,0,0]
[0,0,0,0,0,0]
[0,0,0,0,0,0]
[0,0,0,0,0,0]
[0,0,1,0,1,0]
```

would change to:

```
[0,1,0,1]
[0,0,0,0]
[0,0,0,0]
[0,1,1,0]
```

This is the code that I am using to compute:

```
def remove(matrix):
    for i, x in reversed(list(enumerate(matrix))):
        if np.all(matrix == 0, axis=0)[i] and np.all(matrix == 0, axis=1)[i]:
            matrix = np.delete(matrix,i,axis=0)
            matrix = np.delete(matrix,i,axis=1)
    return matrix
```

After testing this line is taking the most time by far:

```
if np.all(matrix == 0, axis=0)[i] and np.all(matrix == 0, axis=1)[i]:
```

Is there a more appropriate way to test a row and column in this way? The matrix that I am using is a sparse binary matrix. I am not using any sparse matrix classes just ndarray.

Comment: No- I thought so too at first, but I believe the original question wants to remove columns AND rows simultaneously when BOTH are zero.

Comment: Judging by OP's example, I believe so. The row and column indices of the cross must match of course.

Comment: Yes this is what I mean sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @RamseyBissex Please edit the question with the correct expected output. Also, if possible use a more bigger/generic sample case and show us the expected output.

Comment: There we go should be fixed now thank for your patience.

Comment: @RamseyBissex So, I am guessing you are dealing with square shaped arrays only given the requirements of the problem.

Comment: The input matrix will be a square.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vectorized approach with masking -

```
def remove_vectorized(a):
    mask = a==0
    m_row = ~mask.all(1)
    m_col = ~mask.all(0)
    comb_mask = m_row | m_col
    return a[comb_mask][:,comb_mask] #or a[np.ix_(comb_mask, comb_mask)]
```

**Sample runs**

Case #1 :

```
In [485]: a
Out[485]: 
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])

In [486]: remove_vectorized(a)
Out[486]: 
array([[1, 1],
       [0, 0]])
```

Case #2 :

```
In [489]: a
Out[489]: 
array([[0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0]])

In [490]: remove_vectorized(a)
Out[490]: 
array([[0, 1, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 0]])
```

Comment: I don't believe this answers the original question. This removes all rows or columns that are all zero's, however- I think what the poster wants is to remove the rows *and* columns that *both* are 0's simultaneously. You could fix you post by and'ing the bitmasks with eachother before using them in np.ix_().

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do- evaluate the boolean matrix "matrix == 0" outside of your for loop, and use that matrix instead of reevaluating it every run.

It'd be something like:

```
def remove(matrix):
    binary_matrix = matrix == 0
    for i, x in reversed(list(enumerate(matrix))):
        if np.all(binary_matrix , axis=0)[i] and np.all(binary_matrix , axis=1)[i]:
            matrix = np.delete(matrix,i,axis=0)
            matrix = np.delete(matrix,i,axis=1)
            binary_matrix = np.delete(binary_matrix ,i,axis=0)
            binary_matrix = np.delete(binary_matrix ,i,axis=1)
    return matrix
```